# Joomla's JForms make readonly on edit

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am creating a Joomla 3.0 component and I have a question.

I would like to make some fields read-only in edit mode. They should be set on creation and then be uneditable.

I know three (in my opinion) possible ways to do this.

1. Set the field read-only in the background
2. Load an other form if we are in edit mode where the field is read only defined
3. Use javascript to make the field read-only

I would prefer method 2 (or one if it is simpler), but I don't know how this can be accomplished. How can I know in the getForm() function if we go into the edit mode? Any suggestions :)?

Edit:
At the moment, I am using method 3 which i don't like:

```
<?PHP if ($this->item->id > 0) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text_box = document.getElementById('jform_name');
text_box.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly'); 
</script>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Comment: You should be able to add readonly="true" in xml decalration of the JForm form (if you use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend creating a "read only" form as you then have to maintain sync between the different versions as you update it, basically you break [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

You can set the various attributes of a JForm at run time using `setFieldAttribtue()`.

For example in lots of core components you can find forms being modified:

**`com_admin/models/profile.php`**

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true)
{
    // Get the form.
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_admin.profile', 'profile', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
    if (empty($form))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users')->get('change_login_name'))
    {
        $form->setFieldAttribute('username', 'required', 'false');
        $form->setFieldAttribute('username', 'readonly', 'true');
        $form->setFieldAttribute('username', 'description', 'COM_ADMIN_USER_FIELD_NOCHANGE_USERNAME_DESC');
    }

    return $form;
}
```

In some of our components we not only set the `readonly` attribute but we also set the `class` so we can style the field appropriately.

```
$form->setFieldAttribute('name', 'class', 'readonly');
$form->setFieldAttribute('name', 'readonly', 'true');
```

Comment: This is great, didn't know that. But one last question remains. How can i determine if I'm editing or creating the product?

Comment: Found it myself, it's $this->getState('profile.id') (Profile = 2nd parm of loadForm, id = value of the field), this returns the id and if it's set i'm editing ;)